# Как правильно выполнить мультизапрос из php в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго дня, нашел способ как все-таки с помощью одного SQL, развернуть EAV в нужную мне таблицу. Но возникла проблема. Не могу выполнить этот запрос с помощью PHP. Если его запускаю в том же Navicat, то все отлично работает.

вот код функции в php.

```
$query = "SET @SQL = NULL;";
$query .= "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(custom_fields.field_title = ''', fields_to.titleindb,   ''', value, NULL)) AS ', fields_to.titleindb ) ) INTO @SQL FROM fields_to;";
$query .= "SET @SQL = CONCAT( 'SELECT cart_to.*, ', @SQL, ' FROM cart_to, custom_fields WHERE cart_to.id_to = custom_fields.id_to GROUP BY id_to;' );";
$query .= "SELECT @SQL;";
$query .= "PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;";
$query .= "EXECUTE stmt;";
$query .= "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

$res = mysqli_query($conDB, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($query));

$arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}
```

`$conDB` рабочий, проверял заменой всего этого на простой селект.

Вот полный запрос без php.

```
SET @SQL = NULL;


SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(custom_fields.field_title = ''',
            fields_to.titleindb,
            ''', value, NULL)) AS ',
            fields_to.titleindb
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    fields_to;


SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT cart_to.*, ',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM cart_to, custom_fields WHERE cart_to.id_to = custom_fields.id_to GROUP BY id_to;'
);

PREPARE stmt
FROM
    @SQL;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Получаю ошибку типа:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...
```

Comment: Сделать хранимую процедуру с этим текстом. Или выполнять по одному предложению. Хотя гораздо проще будет выполнить только запрос получающий колонки и результат при этом получать не в mysql переменную а получить его в php. После чего в php сформировать итоговый запрос (т.е. переписать его формирование с языка mysql на php), благо функционал по работе со строками у php заметно больше чем у MySQL. И наконец выполнить полученный запрос.

Comment: т.е переменную сформировать запросом по колонкам, сформировать запрос, и его уже отправить, я верно понял?

Comment: Ну да. И никаких execute immediate писать не надо будет. вы просто передадите готовый запрос

Comment: Спасибо большое, с помощью всех советов понял как правильно все-таки это реализовывать.

Answer (score 2):

Так и выполнить. Для выполнения запросов в mysqli служит функция  mysqli_query(). Вот её и надо вызвать столько раз, сколько запросов надо выполнить (пару лишних запросов я убрал)

```
mysqli_query($conDB, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(custom_fields.field_title = ''', fields_to.titleindb,   ''', value, NULL)) AS ', fields_to.titleindb ) ) INTO @SQL FROM fields_to");
mysqli_query($conDB, "SET @SQL = CONCAT( 'SELECT cart_to.*, ', @SQL, ' FROM cart_to, custom_fields WHERE cart_to.id_to = custom_fields.id_to GROUP BY id_to;' )");
mysqli_query($conDB, "PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL");
$res = mysqli_query($conDB, "EXECUTE stmt");
mysqli_query($conDB, "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt");
$all = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

На заметку: вот это вот, `or trigger_error(mysqli_error($query));` во-первых, не будет работать, а во-вторых, не нужно писать после каждого запроса. Надо [соединиться с mysqli как показано здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect), и БД начнет сообщать об ошибках сама по себе, без всякого дополнительного кода

Comment: Спасибо ответ более чем понятен, т.е собрать кучку запросов в одну строку и сделать через `mysqli_query` нельзя. Но я так понимаю это плохое все-таки решение. Лучше выполнить как написал Mike в комментарии под вопросом?

Comment: Не понял, откуда такой вывод, что это "плохое" решение?

Comment: А как же `mysqli_multi_query`?

Comment: mysqli_multi_query - это очень сложный инструмент, с которым надо уметь обращаться. так что лучше его не трогать.

Comment: 2 Ипатьев, я имею ввиду вообще в рамках решения моей задачи. Т.е мне придется сделать n-е количество запросов к БД. А вы все правильно написали, конкретно на мой вопрос ответ был получен.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью коллег выше родил вот такое решение. Все работает. По итогу имею 2 запроса. Остальное формирую на php.

```
global $conDB;

$query = "SELECT fields_to.titleindb FROM fields_to";

$res = mysqli_query($conDB, $query);
$arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $arr[] = "MAX(IF(custom_fields.field_title = '" . $row['titleindb'] . "', value, NULL)) AS " . $row['titleindb'];
}

$str = implode(',', $arr);
$str = "SELECT cart_to.*," . $str . " FROM cart_to, custom_fields WHERE cart_to.id_to = custom_fields.id_to GROUP BY id_to;";
$res = mysqli_query($conDB, $str);
$arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}

return $arr;
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, оптимизировал. И поправил.